# Correct way to get Scroll Position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window, react-dom

In my application, I want to determine the current scroll position, so I have been using this to do so (source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/get+current+scroll+position+javascript)

```
window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

**Problem:** When I console.log this, it only returns 0 when the page is not positioned and the top.

**Question:** Is there an alternative way to get the current scroll position?

Answer (score 2):

Try `window.scrollY`.

> The read-only scrollY property of the Window interface returns the
> number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

Answer (score 2):

recently i had the same problem. So in order to get the position as a percentage I end up do the following

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

    const maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    console.log((window.pageYOffset * 100) / maxHeight);
});
```

We subtract `window.innerHeight` from `document.body.scrollHeight` besause `window.pageYOffset` represents the top of the viewport. So in order for `window.pageYOffset` to match `document.body.scrollHeight` we do the above subtraction.

PS.: The above returns a float number. you can use `parseInt(...)` to convert it to integer if you'd like.

Comment: window.pageYOffset is deprecated

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset#browser_compatibility) and to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=pageYOffset%20) it is not... how did you figure it is deprecated?

Comment: VSCode TypeScript extension is marking it as deprecated "This is a legacy alias of scrollY."

Answer (score 0):

```
const maxHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
```

In modern web development, it's recommended to use the `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` property instead of `document.body.scrollHeight` when you want to access the total scrollable height of the document, as the former is more reliable and works consistently across browsers.